# Removing Space in a number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have gone through many solutions for removing of space in a number but my data is as below:-

( 76,120.04 )

Here space in staring of number, after comma, & ending of number also. So in this case trim or substitute formula doesn't work.

Comment: Are the parentheses included on the sheet or are those only for display purposes in the question?

Comment: Question is not fully clear. Please edit to include some additional information. Similar to what Vegard asked, do you want to keep the spaces before and after the number, just removing the one after the comma? or do you want those spaces gone too?

Comment: Why doesn't  `SUBSTITUTE` work? Can you put the formula used?

Comment: Dear All 
My question is:- When space found between word or number, it's easily removed by using F# trim or substitute or Ctrl+C & paste. But in my data space found like (   54, 140. 32  ). So if you copy this data to excel you will found 7 time space & while using above formula am not able to solve my issue. Hope now my question is clear to all of you, kindly help on this.

Comment: Dear All
I have got the solution. Thanks @martin!

Answer (score 3):

`TRIM` will remove leading and trailing spaces, but not ones in the middle.

`SUBSTITUTE` does work, however, if we assume that all you want to do is remove all spaces:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1; " "; "")
```

[image]

If `SUBSTITUTE` fails to remove all the spaces, it may be because they are non-breaking -- see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/308117/277757).

Note that it's not necessary to use `TRIM` prior to using `SUBSTITUTE` if the space characters are all the same. It's also possible to chain `SUBSTITUTE` with itself -- refer to the linked answer for an example.

`SUBSTITUTE` can also be modified to [target only specific instances](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the leading and trailing by using the following code. Where cell A1 contains the value that you are trimming:
`=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160),CHAR(32)))`

After you will have to copy and paste the value to remove the formula, unless someone else knows how to do that automatically.

Comment: Thanks Martin...it's done. Really it's help me a lot! Thanks Again!